# Parallel execution using TestNg Selenium in a POM framework overwriting the data object class

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pageobjects, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to run two test classes in parallel both are using data providers pointing to different excel sheets. Sequentially it runs fine, but while running it in parallel it seems like the test object class which is holding all the test data is getting overwritten. Below is the data provider
Class 1

```
  @DataProvider(name = "tradeData"  ) 
   public Object[][] createMessage() {
   return ExcelUtils
    .getDataFromExcelSheet("TestSheet1", LOADTESTDATAPROVIDER);
    }}
```

Class 2

```
 @DataProvider(name = "tradeData")
   public Object[][] createMessage() {
   return ExcelUtils
    .getDataFromExcelSheet("TestSheet2", LOADTESTDATAPROVIDER);
    }
```

The data is being returned correctly from the excel but it seems like it is getting overwritten when placed into the object class. The data object class is being initialized from both test classes something like this

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "tradeData")
  public void connectAndPushMessage(String sellerName,
   String buyerName,
   String SIN){

testMessage tMessage = new testMessage();
tMessage.setSellerName(sellerName);
tMessage.setBuyerName(buyerName);
tMessage.setSIN(SIN);
    }
```

Below is the testng.xml that I have used.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Parallel Testing" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test run 1">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.xxx.performance.InjectTrades_TestRun1"/>
        <class name="test.xxx.performance.InjectTrades_TestRun2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
 </suite>



<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Parallel Testing" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
     <test name="Test run 1">
       <classes>
         <class name="test.xxx.performance.InjectTrades_TestRun1"/>
        </classes>
     </test>

<test name="test run 2">
    <classes>
  <class name="test.xxx.performance.InjectTrades_TestRun2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I am getting the same result from both xmls so rather six distinct messages being created/pushed into the system(based on two excel sheets) the code is pushing three distinct messages repeated twice. I was/am under the impression that testNg should have take care of this as both classes/tests are running as separate threads.

**EDIT**
Below is the snippet of the Test object class. All attributes are declared private

```
public class testMessage{

private String currentBusinessDate;
private String sellerName = "";
private String buyerName= "";
private String sin= "";
....
public testMessage() {
cTradeID = "T" + CommonUtils.randomNumber(12);
sRef = CommonUtils.randomNumber(12);
requestId = "1" + CommonUtils.randomNumber(5);
settlementRequestStateCode = "New";
currencyTypeCode = "USD";
 }

public String getCurrentBusinessDate() {
return currentBusinessDate;
  }

public void setCurrentBusinessDate(String currentBusinessDate) {
this.currentBusinessDate = currentBusinessDate;
}
 public String getsellerName () {
return currentBusinessDate;
}

 public void setsellerName (String currentBusinessDate) {
  this.currentBusinessDate = currentBusinessDate;
 }
 public String getBuyerName () {
  return currentBusinessDate;
  }

  public void setBuyerName (String currentBusinessDate) {
   this.currentBusinessDate = currentBusinessDate;
   }
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Used TestNG version is not mentioned, also `ExcelUtils.getDataFromExcelSheet` implementation is not shared, but both these 2 things might be related to such unexpected behavior.

I'm going to share my experiment result in order to confirm, that **there is no issue with the TestNG parallelization itself**, at least for **TestNG 7.5**.

*Test Class 1*

```
class T1 {

    @Test(dataProvider = "tradeData")
    public void connectAndPushMessage(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "tradeData")
    public Object[][] createMessage() {
        return new Object[]{
                { "T1.createMessage-data-1" },
                { "T1.createMessage-data-2" },
                { "T1.createMessage-data-3" },
        };
    }
}
```

*Test Class 2*

```
class T2 {

    @Test(dataProvider = "tradeData")
    public void connectAndPushMessage(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "tradeData")
    public Object[][] createMessage() {
        return new Object[]{
                { "T2.createMessage-data-1" },
                { "T2.createMessage-data-2" },
                { "T2.createMessage-data-3" },
        };
    }
}
```

*testng.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parallel Testing" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test run 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="samples.T1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="test run 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="samples.T2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Output:

```
T1.createMessage-data-1
T2.createMessage-data-1
T2.createMessage-data-2
T1.createMessage-data-2
T2.createMessage-data-3
T1.createMessage-data-3
```

The same for

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parallel Testing" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test run 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="samples.T1"/>
            <class name="samples.T2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Try to recheck this with **TestNG 7.5**, and look at your `ExcelUtils.getDataFromExcelSheet` method implementation, it should be thread-safe.

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for the reply, I verified that the data is being passed correctly from the excel. It's the setters that are either overwriting or holding on to the state of the object. I have added a snippet of the test object class.

Comment: Also when I added a random delay in one class and not in other the data got created successfully pointing that the data is being passed correctly but somehow getting messed up in the test object class when the classes runs in parallel.

Comment: @EvereBuddy I've looked at your test object class. Since all the fields are `non-static` and each test instantiates the own `testMessage` object (its own local method variable), I cannot see any code issue here. I suggest doing a set of experiments. 1) Let's each test just will print it's input data and nothing more. 2) Let's each test just will create a testMessage and will print it's internal fields and nothing more. 3) Let's each test will utilize `testMessage` objects in the way, you're expected to use them and print it's data at the moment you think they were overwritten.